# Thread.Sleep uses 100% from one system processor in a background thread

Tags: .net, vb.net

The project is targeted to .net 2.0. I'm instancing a method in a new thread using:

```
myThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf myClass.MyMethod)
myThread.Start()
```

The sub is like this:

```
Sub myMethod()
  Dim fs As New IO.FileInfo(sFile)
  While Not DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,
                     dtCurrentTime, Now()) > iTimeOutInSeconds
    fs.Refresh()
    If fs.Exists Then
      fs.Refresh()
      If fs.Length > 0 AndAlso fs.Length = iGrowing Then
        bFileExists = True
        Exit While
      End If
      iGrowing = fs.Length
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End If
  End While
End Sub
```

I'm waiting until a file stops growing. The problem is if I call it from the main thread, like:

```
Call myClass.MyMethod()
```

It is working properly, very little of processor power is consumed. But if I call it in a separate thread is consuming all processor power in one core machines, or one core in multi core machines.
Anyone know an alternative way of doing that "Delay" without overtaking the procesor?

Comment: This is extremely fragile code. What if the process responsible for "growing" the file gets briefly pre-empted? Your code would then erroneously assume that the file is finished growing, and proceed to do whatever it is that it is going to do. Oops, then the other process goes back to modifying the file! You need to use a notification, rather than continuous polling. Let the other program *tell you* when it is done modifying the file.

Comment: This code burns 100% core when the file does not exist.  DateDiff() returns a number, using the Not operator on a number makes no sense at all.  Hard to guess what was intended.

Comment: @HansPassant - Perhaps you missed the `> iTimeOutInSeconds` at the end of that line?  :)

Comment: I certainly did.  The hardest bugs to find in source code is in code that's scrolled off the screen :)  It still burns 100% core for a while.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your directions and for your time even this is a mockup code to help explaining the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have this code:

```
While Not (...)
    If fs.Exists Then
        ' do stuff
        Thread.Sleep(...)
    End If
End While
```

So if the file doesn't exist, there's no sleep.

I can't say offhand why you would have different behavior on the main thread than on a background thread. Are you sure that's what is happening?

Comment: I tried the code again and, yes, working fine if executed on main thread, eating processor resources (and working) if executed on separate thread